# How to set major and minor grid lines using Androidplot?

Tags: android, androidplot

I’m trying to implement the following chart using Androidplot, and I’m wondering how to set the major and minor grids as shown in the picture with Androidplot? Is it using setLinesPerRangeLabel to achieve it? I’m new to Androidplot so some sample code will be of great help, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing around with setRangeStep() and setLinesPerRangeLabel() (use setDomainStep() & setLinesPerDomainLabel() for domain)

For the step I use StepMode.SUBDIVIDE. When the setLinesPer[Range/Domain]Label is high enough you should start to see the thicker graph lines.